# Non-negative Quadratic forms with Exterior Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra, quadratic-forms

Hello All,

I apologize if the following question is too elementary. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Let $n\geqslant 4$, $X$ be an $n$-dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $T:\Lambda^{2}(X)\rightarrow \Lambda^{2}(X)$ be a symmetric linear operator satisfying 
$$
\langle T(\omega),\omega\rangle\geqslant 0,\text{ for all }\omega\in \Lambda^{2}(X)\text{ with }\omega\wedge\omega=0.
$$
Is it true that, for some $A\in \Lambda^{4}(X)$, 
$$
\langle T(\omega),\omega\rangle\geqslant 0,\text{ for all }\omega\in \Lambda^{2}(X)\text{ with }\langle A;\omega\wedge\omega\rangle=0?
$$

Comment: It may have some some connection with the following thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118037/on-the-positive-definiteness-of-a-linear-combination-of-matrices